# Count Specific lines in a text file (that start with a number)

Tags: vb.net

As a part of an application that i am building in VB.net, i am trying to import multiple txt files and be able to count how many lines of that file start with a specific number (for example 1) and show it in a message box.

Here is my code so far:

```
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each File In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                For Each fileName In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                   For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName)
                   Dim Linecount = line.count
                        If line.StartsWith("1") Then
                        MsgBox(LineCount)
                        End If
                   Next
                Next
        Next
```

The above code does not work as it gives me wrong number of lines. In my txt file i have only one line that starts with "1".

Answer (score 0):

You are just showing the number of characters in each line here:

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName)
     Dim Linecount = line.Count ' Number of characters
```

You could use LINQ to get the number of lines that start with one:

```
Dim lineWithOne = File.ReadLines(fileName).Count(Function(l) l.StartsWith("1"))
```

If you don't want or can't use LINQ, this is the classic way:

```
Dim lineWithOne = 0
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName)
    If line.StartsWith("1") Then lineWithOne += 1
Next
```

Comment: I used the classic way but i have a problem... If the txt file contains more than one lines starting with "1" then the messagebox appears one time per line. For example it finds the first line and it displays the message box. I press OK and then it displays again for the second line.

I would like to have the total number of lines for all the txt files that are being imported.

Comment: So why do you show the messagebox in the loop? Just count there and  show the result afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works if you import one file. How about counting in more than one files?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Do you want to sum the count of all files which lines start with "1"? Then just increase the counter until you have counted all files. Or do you want to get a result for every file, then use multiple variables.